# Understanding the One-Many relation

Tags: sql-server

I need help understanding of One-to-Many relationships between two tables in SQL Server.

Suppose there are two tables: an `Author` table (`AuthorId`, `AuthorName`) and a `Book` table (`BookId`, `BookName`). Also suppose each `Book` just has one `Author` , but an `Author` can have many `Book`s.

If there were a field on the `Author` table that would keep a list of `Book` (written by this author) my problem would be solved and I would understand this. But this isn't right.

So how is the list of `Book`s by each `Author` determined with a one-to-many relationship? Where are the `BookId` values of an `Author` kept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How the list of books of each author is determined by a one-to-many relationship? Where the address of this books id is kept?

Put an `AuthorID` field in the `Books` table. To know the list of books an author has written, you `SELECT` from the `Books` table based on that `AuthorID`. If you also want to know, for example, the Author's name in the same query, you use a `JOIN`.

Comment: Adding that if a book can have multiple authors, one could create BookAuthor table with a composite primary key consisting of AuthorID and BookID (also with a FK on each column) to resolve the many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

The book table will need another column called AuthorID.  i.e

author table (AuthorId, AuthorName) and a book table (BookId, BookName, AuthorID)